# Youtube force language of auto-generated subtitles

Tags: youtube, video, subtitles, text, translation

It happens to me countless times. Just for an example,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djzGkEWzCwM

the language options of the closed captions only have one auto-generated option, which is "Korean (auto-generated)"; It is obviously wrong as the video is in English.

Is there an way I can force it to be "English (auto-generated)"?